# How to route functions with parameters in python using Firebase?

Tags: python, node.js, database, firebase

I am new to using databases and Firebase, and I made a function, restful API, that takes in 4 parameters. How would I route it to my Firebase database such that the address can take in the parameters? Also, when do I use the methods parameter when routing? I'm new to all of this and would appreciate some help.

For example:

```
db = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://db.firebaseio.com")
def foo(a, b, c, d):
    """code that PUT data from a b c d to Firebase"""
```

And I want to route it so that I can do something like

```
/foo/<a>/<b>/<c>/<d>
```

and works with Firebase, any ideas ?

Comment: Give a minimal working example and read "how to ask".

Comment: @buhtz thanks I edited my post